# UITableView with Scrolling UICollectionView of WKWebView cells

Tags: ios, uitableview, uicollectionview, wkwebview

I am thinking of creating a `UITableView`. Each cell in the `UITableView` would contain a horizontally scrolling `UICollectionView`. Each `UICollectionViewCell` would basically have a `WKWebView` as its sole content. I am thinking of having about 10 rows with 10 cells in each row. Each `WKWebView` would be loading a small amount of javascript (to display an item - name, image, etc).

I know how to accomplish the above. My question is - is this a wise way to display 100 bits of `javascript`, or is 100 simply an obscene number of `WKWebViews` for one page? If done properly, could this work out well?

If this plan in not outrageous, I would be thankful to hear any pitfalls I should watch out for. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The advice I received was that this would be a very expensive operation and probably not a good idea. This could be determined through testing, but would most likely be too much of a load for most devices and would probably be extremely slow to load, at the best.